# How can I combine unicode to use it in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need an L with a dot above (so basically U+1E36, but with the dot above the L) to include it in the title, e.g.

```
ggplot() + geom_line()  + labs(title = expression(paste("The title is ", frac(L with dot above,L))))
```

Unfortunately, I can`t find the Unicode for this, and I don't know how to combine Unicode, so it's working in ggplot. So, how can I do that? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dot(L)` in an expression to put a dot over it:

```
ggplot() + geom_line()  + labs(title = expression(paste("The title is ", frac(dot(L),L))))
```

See `?plotmath` for the list of things that work in expressions in titles and labels.

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode for "dot above previous character" is `U+0307`, so you can do:

```r
ggplot() + 
  geom_line() + 
  labs(title = "The title is L\u0307") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 50))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: That works for me on some output devices, but others write it as an L followed by a box.

Comment: @user2554330 yes, it depends on whether the device has the capability of handling the higher Unicode values. The question specifically asked for how to combine Unicode values, hence this answer. However, your answer was a good practical working solution and got my upvote.